# How to show ModelState validation failure results from a form within a layout page (not typical controller/view)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-layout

This must have been asked before, but a couple of hours searching have yielded nothing remotely close.

In the footer of my **layout page** (not a typical view) I have a *"Subscribe to our Newsletter"* form.  This means that form shows for every view within my web site.  I am trying to achieve the following:

1. User submits their details in the form
2. If successful, they are redirected to a "thank you" page (completed)
3. If there's an error, they are redirected back and the error is displayed in the form

However, item 3 is tricky because where they are redirected back to depends on the URL (controller/action) they were originally at.

The closest solution I've found is to redirect back to `Request.UrlReferrer`, but this is a redirect, and so loses the ModelState!

My code so far is:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(Models.Subscribe subscribe)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View( /* Dynamically return the user to their PREVIOUS location with the invalid ModelState object */, subscribe);
        }
        else
        {
            // Removed for brevity - Capture email
            return View("Subscribed"); // Thank you view (working)      
        }
    }
}
```

### Update following comments

Simply passing the model back with it's invalid ModelState forces an error:

> The view 'Subscribe' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.

This is to be expected, because the user wasn't on a "Subscribe" view, because the form is within the layout page!

Comment: Put the cursor on `View` and press F12. You will see the overloads.

Comment: I don't see anything about a previous view.  This is a layout page, so I'm not simply returning the "same" view as the controller normally would, nor do I *know* the view the user is currently on.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant this `How do I get the controller/action`

Comment: I think what you want is to include a partial at the bottom of each page.  The partial would contain an <iframe> that loads your form page.  If you want to remove the form once it's successfully submitted you might have to store a session variable and check that in your partial's code before populating the iframe.  (using layout for dynamic content seems like it would lead to looping...)  You could also handle this in the layout using a client-side post. (javascript)

Comment: Sorry but iframes are not going to be acceptable due to accessibility reasons.  Research so far leads me to agree that the only solution is client-side posting.  Surely this is the same challenge designers face when using multiple forms in the same view, so I can't understand why solutions are so sparse....?